# Android | SImpleDateFormat | String to Date | MMM, yyyy

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to parse a date from

"May,2021"

to

"05-2021"

How can I do that in a simplest way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
String time = df.format(date);
```

The date object has your date "May,2021"